# How do I read only a specific part of the string in Android Studio?

Tags: android

If a send a string in the following format: 1234,1234,1234,1234; from Arduino to Android Studio (java (intelliJ)) based. with the amount of characters between every komma changing. How do i make it so that my code only reads the string from for example 0 to the , Or from the first , to the second ,?

Comment: android studio is an IDE not a programming language. and add an example

Comment: The example is sending a string in that format. I just want to know how I read only a specific part from such a string. But that string could also be 10,200,30,400000; So I just basically want to know how I get it to read from a komma till it reads another komma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the input string based on any special character,in your case `,`, as follows

```
String inputString = "1234,1234,1234,1234";
String[] separated = inputString.split(",");

Log.i("MainActivity",separated[0]) // prints the first string which is 1234

// to loop over all strings
for(String s : separated){
     Log.i("MainActivity",s)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java, I would recommend looking into the Java.String.split() method. This method will split your string in an array of strings, depending on your delimiter. For example :

```
  String s = "1234,1234,1234,1234";
  String[] result = s.split(",");
```

Comment: So if I see this correctly it will split the string between every comma and then put it into an array. And if I were to call result[1] later i would get 1234 of the first part?

Comment: You would get the second set with result[1], since indexes start at 0. To get the first element, you would have to do result[0] . Hope this helps!